# How do I create a javascript to create a cookie when user comes to site and do nothing at first visit, and do something else after first visit

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to create a cookie when user comes to site and the video will play at first visit only. I'm using quicktime to play mp4 video

what is the best way to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can store a value in the cookie like "videoPlayed=1" once video has been played. Then until cookie is invalid or suppressed, user won't see the video again.

Then in your code you have to extract the cookie, and only plays video if the special videoPlayed value is missing.

You can find information about cookie manipulation [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).